# Why is truffle migration failing to deploy contracts? "cannot read options of undefined"

Tags: ganache, truffle-migration

I am trying to deploy a local version of [SushiSwap](https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap) on a local test Ethereum chain.
I am using [Ganache](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/ganache/quickstart) and [Truffle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/) to deploy the smart contracts locally.

When I run `truffle migrate` and attempt to deploy any of the contracts, the [second file](https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap/blob/master/migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js) in the migrations `2_deploy_contracts.js` fails with an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined at Contract (C:\Users\O\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\contract\index.js:31:1)`

For reference here is the code. I have added the SushiToken.sol contract to deploy.

```
var SushiToken = artifacts.require("SushiToken");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SushiToken()); //This new line throws the error
};
```

**Some more context:**

`SushiToken()` is an instance of SushiToken.sol. See line 1 in the above code. The code still fails if I add the `.sol` extension to the above code.

**This leads me to my question:**

Why is truffle failing to deploy the contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work :

```
const SushiToken = artifacts.require("./SushiToken.sol")

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(SushiToken);
};
```

You just need to replace `SushiToken()` by `SushiToken`.